# How to begin repairing repository

Tags: linux, mercurial

We just recreated all of our repos a week ago and today we're already near that point.  I need to figure out why this keeps happening...

```
$hg verify
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
 smartdox/application/helpers/common_helper.php@?: rev 1 points to unexpected changeset 10
 (expected )
 smartdox/application/helpers/common_helper.php@?: fbe7ec6785e5 not in manifests
 smartdox/application/libraries/MY_Model.php@?: rev 1 points to unexpected changeset 10
 (expected )
 smartdox/application/libraries/MY_Model.php@?: d84e95aff93f not in manifests
 smartdox/application/product_customizers/Proposals - CA Integrated/product.php@?: rev 1 points to unexpected changeset 2
 (expected 7)
 smartdox/application/product_customizers/Proposals - CA Specialty/custom.js@?: rev 1 points to unexpected changeset 2
 (expected 7)
 smartdox/application/product_customizers/Proposals - CA Specialty/product.php@?: rev 1 points to unexpected changeset 2
 (expected 7)
 smartdox/application/product_customizers/Proposals - GA Integrated/product.php@?: rev 1 points to unexpected changeset 2
 (expected 7)
 smartdox/application/product_customizers/Proposals - NY Combined/custom.js@?: rev 1 points to unexpected changeset 5
 (expected 10)
 smartdox/application/product_customizers/Proposals - NY Combined/custom.js@?: rev 2 points to unexpected changeset 6
 (expected 12)
 smartdox/application/product_customizers/Proposals - NY Combined/product.php@?: rev 1 points to unexpected changeset 2
 (expected 7)
 smartdox/application/views/help/training.php@?: rev 1 points to unexpected changeset 7
 (expected 6)
 smartdox/css/admin.css@?: rev 1 points to nonexistent changeset 26
 (expected )
 smartdox/css/admin.css@?: 5c92b2914085 not in manifests
```

I know we need to recreate the repo, but I need to determine the actual source of the problem so I know why this keeps happening.  Anyone have any thoughts on how I can investigate/fix these issues?  https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption isn't as helpful as I would've hoped... it doesn't outline what's going on with `rev x points to unexpected changeset x`

It seems like Mercurial should be transactional and thus should never allow us to corrupt our repositories unless we go in and manually delete files.

**UPDATE**

We believe that samba is the problem.  We use it to map linux drives on windows so we can use Tortoise HG.  We're in the process of coming up with alternative solutions.

Comment: Does someone try to rewrite the history at some point ? What software do you use to access the repo ?

Comment: Mercurial is append-only when operating on the repository, so it should be indeed be robust. Maybe it got corrupted by something external? (e.g. a virus scanner)

Answer (score 7):

This *never* happens in normal usage.  Most sites have repos for years without ever seeing `hg verify` say a thing.

The only times I've seen this has been caused by one of:

- people deleting files too aggressively. For example: `find . -name '*.bak' | xargs rm`.  That seems really safe, but it deletes files from down in `repo/.hg/store` which is a no-user-go-zone
- people modifying files too aggressively.  For example `find repo -type f | xargs perl -pie 's/1999/2000'`.  That feels like you're changing 1999 to 2000 in all files in the working directory, but again you included `repo/.hg/store` and now your files are corrupt
- people using **any** mechanism other than `hg push, pull, and clone` to move changes or changesets from one machine to another.

That last is worth another list.  Any of these are suspect:

- repo on a file server (especially windows/smb) with `hg` run on local machines
- dropbox-style synchronization of .hg directories

The Mercurial authors work really hard to keep things *correct* when you're acting on a repository that's on a remote file server, but the file server protocols primitives just aren't there.  For example, `hg clone` creates hard links, which NTFS supports, and on local systems the get-link-count call returns the current number even if it's greater than 1, but when windows clients are querying NTFS-hosted files over smb some versions of windows always return a link count of 1, which tells mercurial no other clone is using that file, so it can be modified without first making a copy.

I think that last one has been worked around in Mercurial, but the underlying imperative is that if "changes" are coming and going over your network cable initiated by *any* command other than push, pull, or clone you're asking for trouble, and you need to embrace the distributed nature of DVCS and have a truly local clone.

If your corruption is caused by neither overly-broad recursive commands nor file server nonsense, then it's something I've not previously seen.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that many file system commands should be told to ignore anything in the `.hg` directory, if possible

Comment: Thanks... is it possible adjusting permissions or owners within .hg could affect this?  Sometimes we just do `chmod 775 -R *` and include the .hg directories

Comment: The repositories are on a Linux server and we use TortoiseHG.  I've fixed the umask so we shouldn't need to manually adjust permissions anymore.

Comment: umask (and sticky group bit) are the right way to avoid having to set permissions, but I don't think they caused this.  Is tortoisehg reading and writing repos on your local disk?  Is all the communication with the linux server via ssh or http?

Answer (score 0):

would [this](http://www.selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2010-March/030853.html) thread on the Mercurial mailing list help?

Comment: That email would be great and helpful if it had an answer. :-\

Comment: sorry; I presume you also took a look at the recommendation in the [follow-up email](http://www.selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2010-March/030854.html) and that the recommendation at the end didn't help either ...